# Clone database for tests with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an existing database. This database is managed via Django application.
In Flask application which uses same database via Sqlalchemy models are populated with *automap_base*:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Base = automap_base()
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user@localhost/database')
Base.prepare(db.engine, reflect=True)
```

Now I'm trying to set up test database, which would be created using same *Base* object:

```
test_engine =create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user@localhost/test-database')
Base.metadata.create_all(test_engine)
```

So, Sqlalchemy creates table and indexes:

```
2014-12-17 16:23:18,499 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine CREATE UNIQUE INDEX core_city_name_key ON core_city (name)
2014-12-17 16:23:18,499 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2014-12-17 16:23:18,501 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2014-12-17 16:23:18,502 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine CREATE UNIQUE INDEX core_city_name_key ON core_city (name)
2014-12-17 16:23:18,502 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2014-12-17 16:23:18,503 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
```

as you can see index creation got executed twice and affects error:

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) relation "core_city_name_key" already exists
```

What am I doing wrong?